# insert custom class into unordered_map c++

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have a problem which probably has a simple solution but I have looked around for a while and still no success.

I have a simple class as follows:

```
class Node{
public:
int value;
bool visited;
Node(int argvalue) {value = argvalue;visited = false; }
bool operator==(const Node& n) {return (value == n.value);}
};

class MyHash {
size_t operator()(const Node& x) const { return std::hash<int>()(x.value); }
};
```

Now when I try to insert I get error and can not understand why? Did I implement my hash-function incorrectly or is the equal operator == not sufficient?

```
unordered_map<Node, int, MyHash> my_items;
my_items.insert(Node(33), 894);
```

Comment: What error would that be? It'll help anyone else who gets the same error to be able to find your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of the [two-parameter insert methods](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) matches `insert(key_type, mapped_type)`, which is what you are attempting.

The map holds `std::pair<const Key, T>`, so you need to insert a pair, either explicitly:

```
my_items.insert(std::make_pair(Node(33), 894));
```

or using brace initialization:

```
my_items.insert({Node(33), 894});
```

You could use the [std::unordered_map::emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) member function, which allows you to pass the constructor arguments of a pair:

```
my_items.emplace(Node(33), 894);
```

Other things:

- `bool Node::operator==` should be const (a comparison should not change the objects being compared)
- `size_t MyHash::operator()(...) const` should be public.

Comment: or more simply `my_items[Node(33)] = 894;`?

Comment: @Dukeling Kind of, but that has different semantics: if an element with key equal to `Node(33)` already exists, it replaces the mapped value.

Comment: Let's not forget about `my_items.emplace(Node(33), 894)`, which works just like the OP expected. It might not have good compiler support yet though.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors. Firstly, `operator()` is `private` in `MyHash` since it is a class and default access for classes is private. Either mark it as `public` or change it to `struct MyHash`.

Secondly, you cannot insert values like that. It will need to be something like `my_items.insert(std::make_pair(Node(33), 894))`;